# Is this specific group finite?

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, gap, computational-algebra

I have the following group presentation:

$G=\left\langle a,b,c\ |\ a^2,b^{11},c^2,(ab)^{4},(ab^2)^6,ab^2abab^{-1}abab^{-2}ab^2ab^{-1},(ac)^3,(bc)^2\right\rangle$

Is $G$ finite?

GAP's `Size(G)` runs out of memory pretty quickly. No surprise there.
I also tried using the ideas in the answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/159217/using-math-software-to-show-that-the-following-groups-are-infinite) to look for homomorphisms onto certain small simple groups, with no luck. And I used [`LowIndexSubgroups()`](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap47.html#X87FBDA2B815A8776) to look for subgroups up to index $30$ with no results.

It's also worth noting that:

- $a$ and $b$ generate a subgroup isomorphic to $M_{11}$ (The Mathieu Group on $11$ points)
- $a$ and $c$ generate a subgroup isomorphic to $D_6$ (The Dihedral group of size $6$)
- $b$ and $c$ generate a subgroup isomorphic to $D_{22}$ (The Dihedral group of size $22$)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where did this presentation come from?

Comment: @lulu I've been exploring some finite groups presented with two generators, then tacking on $c$ and the relations involving $c$. Sometimes you do get a finite group.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73109/discussion-between-verret-and-josh-b).

Comment: Yes, if you leave out one of the letters, the other two will present a group as listed in the question. But if you combine such presentations, it is not guaranteed -- see the example here -- that such groups survive as subgroup. A more stupid example is to take a free cyclic group generated by $a$ and then add relations $b^2$, $abab$ and $ba^2b$. Suddenly the infinite subgroup $<a>$ is only cyclic of order $2$.

Comment: Thank you. That is a good point. It is possible the whole thing could collapse and be the trivial group.

Comment: I checked that it has no proper subgroups up to index $40$, and no simple images up order up to $500$ million. I don't have any further ideas of things to try. The general problem of deciding whether a group defined by a finite presentation is trivial, finite or infinite, etc is known to be undecidable, so it is unsurprising that presentations arise from time to time which are difficult to resolve.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for doing those calculations. At least I didn't miss an obvious trick. I'm not quite done with this question yet though!